# Comparing columns in sql

Tags: sql-server, compare

I want to compare two columns in SQL

```
oldname   newname empid
j11       j12
j12       j13
j13
```

I want to fetch a list of employees who have completed certain certificates.
Let's say emp1 has done j11 cert but later on the certificate name changes to j12. That employee should still be certified. Later on if j12 is changed to j13, that employee should still be considered certified.

Comment: could you show the structure of your employee table?

Answer (score 0):

You should have three tables:

1. Employees (employeeId)
2. Certificates (certificateId)
3. EmployeeCertificates (links Employees to Certificates)

If you give employees and certificates and invariant identifier then it doesn't matter if their names change (this is an important design principle when you build relational databases).

Answer (score 0):

Your table structure should look like web_bod said.
Your query should look something like this:

```
SELECT employeeid, name FROM
    Employees e INNER JOIN EmployeeCertificates ec ON e.id = ec.employeeId
    INNER JOIN Certificates c ON c.id = ec.certificateId
WHERE Certificates.id = ?
```